# Do electret microphones have polarity?

Tags: microphone, polarity, electret

So do electret mics have polarity?
The following circuits seem to contradict each other...

1)

[image: How to wire an electret mic to radios without phantom power on the audio wire]

2)

[image: Electret mic capsule schematic]

Now the problem is one image shows polarity while the other one does not!!
What's the holdup here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they have polarity and it has to be right to work- the output needs to be biased positive with respect to the ground terminal.

The ground/GND terminal should be common with the case, so you can check polarity with a multimeter.

Here, from a [Panasonic Datasheet](http://industrial.panasonic.com/www-data/pdf/ABA5000/ABA5000CE22.pdf), is a typical arrangement:

[image]

The two diagrams you show are equivalent, one is just drawn upside-down (potentially.. as it were.. confusing and not to be encouraged, but still valid).

Comment: This link helped me further! http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-determine-the-polarities-of-a-microphone

Comment: Can I break my mic somehow if I connect it with reverse polarity?